# How to open gnome-terminal and run a compound command

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-terminal

I'm in Ubuntu 20.04LTS with GNOME Terminal 3.36.2. I would like to run two commands, executing the second only if the first succeeds:

```
proc.sh && results.sh
```

I would like to run this in a separate terminal window so I say:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'proc.sh && results.sh'
```

This works. But I get a warning that `-e` is deprecated, and I should be using `--`. However, both `-x` (also deprecated) and `--` are the same and will interpret the entire contents of the quoted text as the executable name, which of course results in a "file not found" error.

So what's the proper way to do this now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint is in the manual:

> `--command`, `-e=COMMAND`
> Split the argument to this option into a program and arguments in the same way a shell would, and execute the resulting command-line inside the terminal.
>
> This option is deprecated. Instead, use `--` to terminate the options, and put the program and arguments to execute after it: for example, instead of `gnome-terminal -e "python3 -q"`, prefer to use `gnome-terminal -- python3 -q`.
>
> Note that the `COMMAND` is not run via a shell: it is split into words and executed as a program. **If shell syntax is required, use the form `gnome-terminal -- sh -c '...'`.**

<sup>([source](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html), emphasis mine)</sup>

In the command you want to run `&&` belongs to the shell syntax. You need a shell to handle it. Therefore:

```
gnome-terminal -- sh -c 'proc.sh && results.sh'
```